# htaccess for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need help with .htaccess
I have website on my localhost with this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now i want to move the site to subdomain.domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/$1 [L]
```

I chaged the url but this doesn'n work maybe because this is subdomain i don't know

hosting details:

```
#   Subdomain Name              Path [?]    
1   subdomain.domain.com    /home/www/subdomain.domain.com
```

my urls are like this

http://website/index.php/contact

with this htaccess i can use

http://website/contact

When i moved the site to the subdomain i can use http://subdomain.website/index.php/contact but when try http://subdomain.website/contact gives me error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? What error is shown? What is the root folder of subdomain? Please clarify.

Comment: OK, please check your Apache's error log -- it will give you the reason for error. But first -- does REAL URL work for you (e.g. `http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/contact` where no rewrite is involved)? It may be nothing to do with redirect but with subdomain configuration (for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this one, it should work for all domains localhost as well as server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Make sure "rewrite_engine = on" on server.

Comment: removed the second line of your code and everything works now :)